# Some noob questions

Tags: 12.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and I've had some issues which I want to make sure are OK.

1. Whenever I boot I get two lines of text. It's hard to read because it flashes very fast, however it's something about edac and not being able to locate the sbridge.
2. I also have an Nvidia GTX 650 graphics card and I'm not sure which proprietary driver to install since they all have the same name and no dates. Which one should I install?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you which driver you install. Usually it is safer to install the latest tested driver such as "Nvidia-319".

You can find a list of available drivers in your 'Software and Updates' app.